# travis build failing because of an apparent circular package dependency

Tags: r, travis-ci, devtools

I have an R package **A** and a package **B**. The package **B** genuinely depends on **A** for some of its functions. The package **A** depends on **B**, but only for testing. So the package dependency is not genuinely circular.

The travis build fails for **A** because upon installing **A** it tries to install **B** only to find **A** is not installed.

How can I tell travis not to worry about **B** until it starts testing?

My thoughts are to:

- Put all of **B**'s dependencies in **A**, leaving **B** independent.
- Leave off the dependency of **A** on **B**, and construct the test as if **B** didn't exist.

But both seem as drastic as abandoning unit testing.

I've mocked up an minimum reproducible example:

https://github.com/HughParsonage/AAAA

https://github.com/HughParsonage/BBBB

When I push `AAAA` to travis, I get:

> ERROR: dependency ‘AAAA’ is not available for package ‘BBBB’
>
> removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BBBB’
>
> Error: Command failed (1)
>
> Execution halted

My actual packages are

**A**:
https://github.com/HughParsonage/grattan

**B**:
https://github.com/HughParsonage/taxstats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you know the answer to this: Just avoid the circular dependency.

There just was an insightful and detailed discussion about a very related situation on the [r-devel list in this thread](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.devel/39463).  You a look at the discussion there; several options were proposed and the original poster was somewhat convinced -- just like you here -- that the standard laws of gravity would not apply to them.

I would just avoid the problem and put the commonalities into a new package `pkgC` upon which `pkgA` and `pkgB` can depend, or even just suggest it.   Another simply solution (also proposed in the thread) is to just merge `pkgA` and `pkgB`.

Comment: Dirk, do you have to live quite so relentlessly in the real world?

Comment: Note also that for CRAN packages, submitting two co-dependent packages (whether suggest or otherwise) simultaneously, with a note to the CRAN maintainers is acceptable. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioc-devel/2015-October/008098.html and https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2013-March/066063.html